# filter variables not containing certain conditions

Tags: r

```
> DF<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3),code=c("A","B","E","NA","A"))
> DF
  id code
1  1    A
2  1    B
3  2    E
4  3   NA
5  3    A
```

I want to remove all `id` where `code` is `A`. Using the below I get a faulty result.

```
> DF%>%group_by(id)%>%filter(!(code=="A"))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
     id code 
  <dbl> <fct>
1     1 B    
2     2 E    
3     3 NA
```

But my desired output is:

```
 id code
1  2    E
```

Any ideas?
Best H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(!any(code == 'A'))

#    id code 
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     2 E
```

Same logic in base R :

```
subset(DF, !ave(code == 'A', id, FUN = any))
```

and `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, .SD[!any(code == 'A')], id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version using `%in%` and `!`

```
DF %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(! "A" %in% code)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[DF[, .I[!'A' %chin% code], id]$V1]
#    id code
#1:  2    E
```